# Dynamic progress bar on form submit in extjs 3.3

Tags: javascript, extjs, user-interface, javascript-framework, extjs3

I am submiting the form from in the extjs 3.3. the back end process will run nearly half an hour after form submit. I need to display the progress information to the user. The message will be return from server. I need to display the server message in the progress bar until the process completed.

My current code

```
Ext.getCmp('columnDetailInfoId').getForm().submit({
    url     : 'callAPIs', 
    timeout : 2000000,
    waitMsg : 'In-Progress...',
    params  : {selectedAppRowNo: Ext.encode(selectedAppRowNo)},

    success : function(){                                             
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title  : 'Info',
            msg    : 'process completed.',
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
            icon   : Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
            animEl : 'mb9',
            width  : 400
        });
    },

    failure : function(form,action){
        var message = action.result.message;

        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title  : 'Error',
            msg    : 'process Failed. Error Message:'+message,
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
            icon   : Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            animEl : 'mb9',
            width  : 500
        });
     }
});
```

I need to display the progress bar instead of wait message. Share your idea or code to implement this scenario.

Comment: for simple process i may update the wait message content while it is progress. Is it possible ?

Comment: What is preventing your from simply using a [progress MessageBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-progress)?